# Any Javascript Regex ReplaceAll by Anonymous Function Implementations Like Groovy's?

Tags: java, javascript, regex, groovy

The following (Java) implementation is part of the GDK:

```
/**
 * Replaces all occurrences of a captured group by the result of a closure on that text.
 * <p/>
 * <p> For examples,
 * <pre>
 *     assert "FOOBAR-FOOBAR-" == "foobar-FooBar-".replaceAll(~"(([fF][oO]{2})[bB]ar)", { Object[] it -> it[0].toUpperCase() })
 * <p/>
 *     Here,
 *          it[0] is the global string of the matched group
 *          it[1] is the first string in the matched group
 *          it[2] is the second string in the matched group
 * <p/>
 * <p/>
 *     assert "FOO-FOO-" == "foobar-FooBar-".replaceAll("(([fF][oO]{2})[bB]ar)", { x, y, z -> z.toUpperCase() })
 * <p/>
 *     Here,
 *          x is the global string of the matched group
 *          y is the first string in the matched group
 *          z is the second string in the matched group
 * </pre>
 * <p>Note that unlike String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement), where the replacement string
 * treats '$' and '\' specially (for group substitution), the result of the closure is converted to a string
 * and that value is used literally for the replacement.</p>
 *
 * @param self    a String
 * @param pattern the capturing regex Pattern
 * @param closure the closure to apply on each captured group
 * @return a String with replaced content
 * @since 1.6.8
 * @see java.util.regex.Matcher#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)
 */
public static String replaceAll(final String self, final Pattern pattern, final Closure closure) {
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(self);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(self.length() + 16);
        do {
            int count = matcher.groupCount();
            List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
                groups.add(matcher.group(i));
            }
            final String replacement = InvokerHelper.toString(closure.call(groups.toArray()));
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
        } while (matcher.find());
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return self;
    }
}
```

Are there any similar implementations out there for Javascript? If not, is it feasible to attempt an implementation oneself; how might one go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question properly, but reading the comments in your example, the sample use cases can be satisfied by the `replace` method of the js String object. `replace` can take a function as its replacement argument:

```
// true
console.log(
    "FOOBAR-FOOBAR-" == "foobar-FooBar-".replace(
        /(([fF][oO]{2})[bB]ar)/g,
        function(  all, capture1, capture2 ) {
            return all.toUpperCase();
        }
    )
);

// true
console.log(
    "FOO-FOO-" == "foobar-FooBar-".replace(
        /(([fF][oO]{2})[bB]ar)/g,
        function( all, capture1, capture2 ) {
            return capture2.toUpperCase();
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Whoa! I did not know `replace` had this "overload"! Let me try it out and I'll let you know how it works out -- it looks like this is exactly what I am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to 'replaceAll' a text in a given String and if we identify the regular expression as a global regular expression we can easily replace all occurrences of a string within an other string value in a given text using Javascript.

How we can enable global regular expression is as simple as adding the "g" identifier following the regular expression.
Using "g" following the regular expression pattern, builtin javascript replace method will replace all matches and all occurences of the given text variable with the new string.

```
var string_variable;
string_variable = "Replace text using javascript replace function within a javascript     string variable";
string_variable = string_variable.replace(/javascript/g, "js");
alert(string_variable);
```

As you can see in the sample javascript codes the implementation or the usage of the replace javascript function is so simple.

Comment: The above solution is , only if you want to do simple replaceAll insted of replace in javaScript function. I think this is what you asked. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry @Ninja, but this won't do.  instead of a replacement string (in your example "js"), I want to use an anonymous function which is called for each match and whose return value is used for the replacement (instead of one string for all replacements).